# Postgres - Move column to another table or Update another column

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert-update, upsert, sql-merge

I have two tables :

> **PRODUCT**       >> for the basic item info. Title, time created etc ...
>
> **PRODUCT_IMAGE** >> for item images. 1 product might have multiple images

**"product_id" in PRODUCT_IMAGE is foreign key for "id" in PRODUCT**

**PRODUCT**

```
id  |   time    |   title   |   image_url
562 |   2019    |   iPhone  |   http://repo.coi/img/3520.png
....
```

**PRODUCT_IMAGE**

```
id  | product_id    |   url             |   is_primary
10  | 4523          |   /ipo/2388/png   | True
....
```

I need to move `image_url` column from `PRODUCT` to `PRODUCT_IMAGE`

> IF `url` already exists in `PRODUCT_IMAGE` then update `is_primary` to
>   `True`
>
> IF NOT then insert new row (`product_id`, `image_url`,
>   `is_primary=False`) to `PRODUCT_IMAGE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This needs an `UPDATE`:

```
update PRODUCT_IMAGE pi
set is_primary = True
from PRODUCT p
where p.id = pi.product_id and p.image_url = pi.url;
```

and then `INSERT`:

```
insert into PRODUCT_IMAGE (product_id, url, is_primary)
select p.id, p.image_url, False
from PRODUCT p
where not exists (
  select 1 from PRODUCT_IMAGE
  where product_id = p.id and url = p.image_url
);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=fe296b4f09adb344386d1fe0ce323de0).

Answer (score 1):

If your DB's version is 9.5+, then can use `insert ... on conflict update` syntax. So, consider using

```
insert into product_image(product_id, url, is_primary) 
select id, image_url, False from product
   on conflict(url) do update 
  set is_primary = True;
```

where `product_image.url` should be `unique` as in the <kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=6291ce29670763a44f05df752c9b43d2)</kbd>